# Why there is no Biber in TexShop as the picture shows?

Tags: biber, texshop

[image: There is no "Biber" in the drop-down list]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpZRo.png)

Every time, when I use biblatex, it says "you should run the Biber". But there is no Biber here.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154778#154778

Comment: You should also look into arara :-) configure one tool in your editor and let your document do the rest!